# How to replace the value of an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have this function that returns an array of objects, every object represent a sticky, what I want is to change the value of "content" everytime I click one of the stickies

```
  handleStickyEdition = (index) => {
    const { currentStage } = this.props
    const stickies = currentStage.get('stickies')
    const updatedStickies = [...stickies]
    console.log(updatedStickies)
  }
```

And the result of calling the console.log is this array of objects:
[image]

If I do `console.log(updatedStickies[index].get('content'))` I will get the content of the object I want to change. For example `name 3`.

How can I replace this `content` with an empty string? in other words, if I click the object in the position 0, how can I make `name 3` equals to `''`

Comment: `updatedStickies[index].content = ' '`

Comment: @guijob This is incorrect, you are trying to mutate the data inside of props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a map like so.

```
this.setState({
  updatedStickies: this.state.updatedStickes.map(sticky => ({
    ...sticky
    content: sticky.id === idOfStickyWeWantToUpdate ? "" : "content"
  }))
});
```

I see you are reading stickies from props, I would suggest having a function in your parent component to run the above code which you can call from your child component if need be.